# Plugged in SD-Card keeps opening windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sd-card

When I plug in an SD-Card into my windows pc, it keeps opening the windows explorer with the prompt 'You need to format this drive'. It assigns new drive letters over and over again. 
There is a Yocto-Linux image on that SD-Card and I need to read that image with win32 disk imager. 
I tested multiple windows machines, card readers and USB ports. This happens with all the SD-cards with that image. I tried to disable AutoPlay in windows, but that did not change the behavior.

[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: Your SD card is dead. Buy a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill That can't be the problem. It works on the linux SoC and as described, it happens with multiple cards.

Comment: So you've made an image on Linux with a file system that Windows doesn't recognise ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Probably, ... But windows shouldn't reopen the explorer until it crashes I think. I thought there might be a solution to this.